# Providing a C interface to a 'Region' map

Tags: c++, c

I decided using a C++ `map` or `unordered_map` is the most appropriate option to store 'Regions' where which can be loaded in arbitrary patterns

The rest of the project is written in C, so I made a C interface:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include "Region.hpp"
static std::unordered_map<uint64_t, void *> Regions;
extern "C" {
void *GetRegion(const uint16_t X, const uint16_t Z, const unsigned char Y) {
    const uint64_t Key = X|((uint64_t)Z<<16)|((uint64_t)Y<<32);
    return Regions.count(Key) ? Regions.at(Key) : NULL;
}
void *CreateRegion(const uint16_t X, const uint16_t Z, const unsigned char Y) {
    const uint64_t Key = X|((uint64_t)Z<<16)|((uint64_t)Y<<32);
    if (Regions.count(Key)) {
        return Regions.at(Key);
    }
    void *const Region = GenerateARegion(X, Z, Y);
    Regions.insert({Key, Region});
    return Region;
}
bool DeleteRegion(const uint16_t X, const uint16_t Z, const unsigned char Y) {
    return Regions.erase(X|((uint64_t)Z<<16)|((uint64_t)Y<<32)) != 0;
}
}
```

I am wondering if there is an elegant way to eliminate the repeated `X|((uint64_t)Z<<16)|((uint64_t)Y<<32)`

Comment: "where which can be loaded"?  I'm struggling to parse that - could you edit to clarify, please?

Comment: Easy:  make it a (presumably inlined) helper function.  It should be local to this CPP file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the global variable `Regions` rings alarm bells for me.  It will make it hard to write independent unit tests for these functions.  Prefer passing an opaque pointer through your C function interface.  In any case, it will be better to declare its value type explicitly rather than `void*`, to give us suitable checking when we insert elements.

The computation of `Key` in each function is repetitive, and needs to be consistent.  It's really worth extracting that as a function.  I'd probably split the interface from the implementation here:

```
// header
#ifndef REGION_H
#define REGION_H

#ifdef __cplusplus__
extern "C" {
#else
#include <stdbool.h>
#endif

void *GetRegion(uint16_t X, uint16_t Z, unsigned char Y);
void *CreateRegion(uint16_t X, uint16_t Z, unsigned char Y);
bool DeleteRegion(uint16_t X, uint16_t Z, unsigned char Y);

#ifdef __cplusplus__
}
#endif
#endif
```

```
// implementation
#include "region.h"
#include "Region.hpp"
#include <unordered_map>

static std::unordered_map<uint64_t, void *> Regions;

static std::unordered_map<uint64_t, void *> Regions;

static uint64_t key_for(uint16_t x, uint64_t z, uint64_t y)
{
    return x | z << 16 | y << 32;
}

void *GetRegion(const uint16_t x, const uint16_t z, const unsigned char y) {
    auto const key = key_for(x, y, z);
    ⋮
}

void *CreateRegion(const uint16_t x, const uint16_t z, const unsigned char y) {
    auto const key = key_for(x, y, z);
    ⋮
}

bool DeleteRegion(const uint16_t x, const uint16_t z, const unsigned char y) {
    auto const key = key_for(x, y, z);
    ⋮
}
```

---

Consider using a different key type, rather than using arithmetic to compose it.  For instance,

```
using Key = std::tuple(unsigned char, uint16_t, uint16_t);

static Key key_for(uint16_t x, uint16_t z, unsigned char y)
{
    return {y, z, x};
}
```

This should give the same sort order if we change to `std::map`.

---

In `GetRegion()`, we look up the key twice here:

> ```
> return Regions.count(Key) ? Regions.at(Key) : NULL;
> ```

It's better to find it just once and reuse the iterator:

```
auto const key = key_for(x, y, z);
auto it = Regions.find(key);
return it == Regions.end() : nullptr : it->second;
```

The same logic can be used in `CreateRegion()`.

---

In `DeleteRegion()` we drop the pointer from the map, but who is responsible for releasing its resources?  Is there a `region_free()` function we need to be calling?

---

## Modified code

Untested, as we're missing `GenerateARegion()` and `FreeARegion()`.

```
#include "region.h"
#include "Region.hpp"
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>

using Key = std::tuple(unsigned char, uint16_t, uint16_t);
static std::unordered_map<Key, Region*> regions;

static Key key_for(uint16_t x, uint16_t z, unsigned char y)
{
    return {y, z, x};
}

void *GetRegion(const uint16_t x, const uint16_t z, const unsigned char y)
{
    auto const key = key_for(x, y, z);
    auto const it = regions.find(key);
    return it == regions.end() : nullptr : it->second;
}

void *CreateRegion(const uint16_t x, const uint16_t z, const unsigned char y) {
    auto const key = key_for(x, y, z);
    auto it = regions.find(key);
    if (it == regions.end()) {
        it = regions.emplace(key, GenerateARegion(x, z, y))->first;
    }
    return it->second;
}

bool DeleteRegion(const uint16_t x, const uint16_t z, const unsigned char y) {
    auto const key = key_for(x, y, z);
    auto const it = regions.find(key);
    if (it == regions.end()) {
        return false;
    }
    FreeARegion(it->second);
    return regions.erase(it) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that C++ `bool` is the same size as C's `_Bool`?

Comment: I honestly don't know; I just accepted from the code under review that a `bool`-returning function can be `extern "C"`.  If you're interested in the answer, it's probably worth looking on [so]. If we can't depend on that, I guess `int` is the appropriate fallback.

Comment: It might be true for the specific compiler, or part of the ABI, so can be counted on given the context, though not part of the ISO standard.  I didn't find any mention at cppreference so thought I'd query.

Comment: Over on SO: [Getting bool from C to C++ and back](//stackoverflow.com/q/40020423/4850040).  Of course it's more than just _size_ that matters - in theory, C++ `bool` and C `_Bool` could have different representations, though in practice that's probably too perverse; in practice, the platform ABI should make them the same, and lacking that, using compilers from the same suite (e.g. gcc and g++) gives the best chance of interoperability.